# Angular component interaction with injection and classReference - practical experience?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a question regarding best practices of component architecture / communication.

Next to property bindings and services i recently noticed the following parent-child setup and wanted to know what you think about it?
Advantage / disadvantage / Use Case / practical experience ?

A clear disadvantage i see is, that all implementation takes place in the parent/main component.

Other aspects can be:

- ChangeDetection
- performance
- hierarchical structuring of big components

I hope the minimal example can illustrate the principle.

Basis of this principle is injection and class reference (see: [break-circularities-with-a-forward-class-reference-forwardref](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#break-circularities-with-a-forward-class-reference-forwardref)).

```js
@Component({
  providers: [
  { provide: MyApp1, useExisting: forwardRef(() => AppComponent) },
  { provide: MyApp2, useExisting: forwardRef(() => AppComponent) },
  { provide: MyApp3, useExisting: forwardRef(() => AppComponent) },
  ],
  selector: "app-root",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"],
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
})

export class AppComponent implements MyApp1, MyApp2, MyApp3 {

  childProp1 = "property of child, defined in parent";
  private iHaveAccessToParentProp = true;

  childMethod1(): void {
    console.log(this.iHaveAccessToParentProp);
  }

}



export abstract class MyApp1 {
  abstract readonly childProp1: string;
  abstract childMethod1(): void;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-myApp1",
  styleUrls: ["./myapp1.component.scss"],
  templateUrl: "./myapp1.component.html",
})
export class MyApp1Component {

  constructor(public app: MyApp1) {
  }
}
```

```html
<!------- myapp1.component.html ----->
 <p>{{ app.childProp1 }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question, this pattern puts all of implementation into the parent "AppComponent".

Frankly, I'm not sure why you would want to do this. The whole point of a Component-based framework like Angular is precisely to break that functionality up, separating each distinct piece of functionality into its own component, so that the components can follow this [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

The goal is to achieve loose [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) and tight [cohesiveness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) in your design.
The pattern that you are describing is exactly the opposite, and so, I believe, would generally be considered bad practice.